# How to get exact outgoing call receiving time?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am implementing one application related to incoming and outgoing call details.

I am getting outgoing call and incoming call details by using brodcast receivers.

The problem is when the incoming call will come the brodcast receiver will rise,

And i make an outgoing call the brodcast receiver raised.

That is fine,but when i click the green button the outgoing call will start,but

i want exact time of answering the call from otherside.

How i get this?

If any one know please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a TelephonyManager

```
if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL) || (intent
                .getAction()
                .equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)))) {

            String phoneState = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Outgoing call");

            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(phoneState)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Incoming call/Outgng call Started");

            }
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(phoneState)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Call ended");
            }
            if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(phoneState)) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Call ringing");
            }
        }
```

Comment: In the manifest register for   <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />. The current state of the call will come in the extras of the Phone State intent. When the phone is ringing, EXTRA_STATE_RINGING will be in extra. When the call is picked, the extra will be EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK. When the call is ended then EXTRA_STATE_IDLE will be in the extras of the intent. By comparing this, you can find the exact call duration.

Comment: when i click gree(outgoing)call button it will directly go state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK,how i will handle.....thanks.

Comment: For the outgoing call, finding the exact time of the receiver picking the call is not possible with the intents.

Comment: Please update your answer with manifest and all functionality so I can understand your answer

Answer (score 1):

Continuously check   when device state is changed from CALL_STATE_IDLE, to [CALL_STATEOFFHOOK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)... It gives the exact time of your call being answered

Comment: this order is not working belongs to out going call....If the incoming call the order is ringing,offhook and ideal.........if the outgoing call the oreder is ,directly got o offhook state and ideal state.how i will handle this.