# How to get outgoing call connected state

Tags: android, telephony

In my application development, I need to do vibration when outgoing call connected, but I can not get the call answered state. I have read some topic about this question, such as:
    [Outgoing call status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099782/outgoing-call-status)

But actually, these questions not be answered correctly. Use BroadcastReceiver can only receive idle, offhook, ringing states, but no active state.

The active state defined in Call.java in internal framework, I have no idea to get this state. I did use reflection method, almost same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652660/accessing-callmanager-in-android, But failed also.

Answer (score -1):

I never tried with outgoing calls but with incoming calls you can play with the THREE STATES YOU'VE mentioned.

1. STATE_RINGING: call is ringing.
2. STATE_OFF_HOOK: if the previous state was RINGING, the call got connected.
3. STATE_IDLE: if prev state was RINGING: Call rejected. If prev state was OFF_HOOK call connected and then disconnected (i.e. completed).

I have code for this implementation for incoming calls. Since you mentioned you can access these states in outgoing calls as well, I think this should work for outgoing calls as well. If you want I can post my code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Outgoing call is different with incoming call, STATE_OFF_HOOK not means connected state, The framework have 9 states defined in Call.java: IDLE, ACTIVE, HOLDING, DIALING, ALERTING, INCOMING, WAITING, DISCONNECTED, DISCONNECTING,  actually I need the ACTIVE state, but I can not.

Comment: If we can get exact outgoing call receiving time, we can get the resolution, see this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136475/how-to-get-exact-outgoing-call-receiving-time  but this topic not be solved also.

Answer (score -2):

After wondering and spending a lot of time on the net I found a way to achieve this...

Just query the call history of the device based on time of your last dialed call, fetch the duration of that call, if found greater than 0 that means your call was accepted and it works perfect.

if someone unable to get it, lets me know I will elaborate it with code.

Comment: Not very useful if you want to quickly check if the connection was made and then move on to some other code. Your solution requires the call to finish.

Comment: Hi , I am also searching the solution for this. Can you advice me with the code .?

Comment: in my project user never picks up call so how can I detect outgoing call is connected